# how to separate views on the same page in virtuemart productdetails and related products

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

I have a page productdetails.php and it below shows related product 
i want to put some condition for related products,but since the view is same the changes i add to related products also get reflect to product details page

like I want to show radio buttons for product details price 
and select list for related products 
any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

In your `layout` pages (any page inside `productdetails/tmpl`) the related products variable is available  `$this->product->customfieldsRelatedProducts`  so you can simply check like.

```
if(sizeof($this->product->customfieldsRelatedProducts) >0){

   // the current viewing product have related products
}else{
  //the current product have no related products
}
```

Hope it helps..